# How to replace second occurrence of a line starting with something in file

Tags: sed

I tried the following code to fully replace the second line starting with `[cols=` but the regexp part (.*) is ignored by sed.

```
sed -i ':a N;$!ba; s/\[cols=.*/\[cols=\"25%\"\]/2' myfile.txt
```

If I remove `.*` , it replaces `[cols=` by `[cols="25%"]` , but not the full line.

Any idea?

Comment: can you add some sample input lines (say 3-5 lines) and complete expected output for that? also, are you using `GNU sed` since you have `-i` without additional argument..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
foo
[cols="3%"]
baz
[cols="12%"]
xyz
[cols="50%"]

$ awk '/\[cols=/ && ++c==2{$0 = "[cols=\"25%\"]"} 1' ip.txt
foo
[cols="3%"]
baz
[cols="25%"]
xyz
[cols="50%"]
```

- `/\[cols=/` match line containing `[cols=`

  - `++c==2` check if the count is `2` (initial value of `c` will be `0` here)
- `$0 = "[cols=\"25%\"]"` change entire line to desired string
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of `$0`

If you have `GNU awk`, use `-i inplace` to write back the changes to input file.